# Receive RTP/UDP with H264 frames/NAL units in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

My SDP looks like below (IP and port may change ofc), video only, contains SPS/PPS and profile/level (real ones, not hardcoded)

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 null
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 192.168.18.26
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=video 5006 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42c029;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LAKY1oB4AiflgHhEI1,aM4BqDXI;
a=control:trackID=1
```

My ExoPlayer implementation is current

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.17.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.17.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-rtsp:2.17.1'
```

And I'm trying to load above SDP using this code

```
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        exoPlayer.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(uri));
        exoPlayer.prepare();
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

which gives me

```
ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
  com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:641)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:611)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
 Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.BundledExtractorsAdapter.init(BundledExtractorsAdapter.java:92)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1020)
....
```

This SDP can be opened by VLC on desktop (common player Windows and Linux, and .NET lib implementation) or mobile (using official LibVLC implementation for Android). **What I'm doing wrong with ExoPlayer?**

Disclaimer: thats not RT<any_letter>P. Just pure RTP with raw NAL units pushed on some ip:port. According to doc ExoPlayer should support [RTP/UDP](https://exoplayer.dev/rtsp.html#supported-network-types) and H264 (but I'm not seeing any `Extractor`...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [THIS](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/10107) issue - currently ExoPlayer doesn't support sideloading and playing SDP file, sadly...